# For holomorphic $f$, $f(\frac{z}{2})= \frac{1}{2}f(z) \Longrightarrow f(z) = z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the open unitary disk $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $\mathbb{\overline{D}}$. If $f(\frac{z}{2})= \frac{1}{2}f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{\overline{D}}$ and $f(1)=1$, then $f(z)=z$ for all $z\in \mathbb{\overline{D}}$.

*Got this as homework. Any hints would be highly appreciated.*

Comment: **Hints:** Compute $f(2^{-k})$, use the identity theorem for holomorphic fuctions.

Comment: "Complex Analysis" in unsuitable as a title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since $f$ is holomorphic it has a unique power series representation about origin,
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k z^k.
$$
Since $f\left(\dfrac{z}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2} f(z)$ we obtain
$$
\frac{c_k}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2}c_k,\quad k=0,1,\ldots.
$$
From this we obtain $c_k=0$ if $k\neq 1$. Therefore $f(z)=c_1z$. We know that $f(1)=1$. Thus $c_1=1$ and $f(z)=z$.

Comment: The question asks for a hint...

Comment: @Mariano: That rarely works here.  Even when the OP asks for a hint, and some people provide hints, someone else will come along with a full solution (in this case just 3 hours later).

Comment: It was really a wonderful solution.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of looking at this is that you are given that $f(z) - z = 0$ for $z = 1$. Then use the condition that $f(z/2) = {1 \over 2}f(z)$ to inductively show that $f(z) - z$ also has zeroes at $z = 2^{-n}$ for all positive integers $n$. Thus the zeroes of $f(z) - z$ have an accumulation point at $z = 0$, which is only possible if $f(z) - z = 0$ for all $z$ since nonzero analytic functions can only have isolated zeroes.